# homeomorphism to a subspace of the Euclidean space

Tags: general-topology

let $S^1$ be the boundary of the unit disc in $E^2$ (the Euclidean space of dimension 2). Is there a topological Space X such that $X\times X$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$?

Comment: I think he means $X \times X$.

Comment: Yes, user1620696 is right. Cartesian Product

Comment: John, you can get the times sign with `\times`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: If $X$ is not connected, then $X\times X$ is not connected, so $X$ would have to be connected. Let $p,q\in X\times X$ with $p\ne q$; show that $(X\times X)\setminus\{p,q\}$ is still connected. It may be helpful to realize that $\{x\}\times X$ and $X\times\{x\}$ are connected for each $x\in X$. Now, what happens when you remove two points from $S^1$?

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: @John: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$

Another argument, using fundamental groups: $π_1(X) × π_1(X) = π_1(X × X) = π_1(S^1) = \Z$.

Update: So $π_1(X)$ is a subgroup of $\Z$ and hence is (isomorphic to) $0$ or $\Z$. Neither $0 × 0$ nor $\Z × \Z$ is isomorphic to $\Z$.

Comment: But then you'd have to show too that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a product of 2 identical groups. It's not quite complete as it stands.

Comment: I'd have to show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a product of 2 identical groups _which are its subgroups_ and that is obvious.